# Using Reg Ex to Match Strings in a Data Frame and Replace - python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, strip

i have data frame that looks like this

```
    value
0   A067-M4FL-CAA-020
1   MRF2-050A-TFC,60 ,R-12,HT
2   moreinfo
3   MZF8-050Z-AAB
4   GoCats
5   MZA2-0580-TFD,60 ,R-669,LT
```

i want to be able to strip `,60 ,R-12,HT` using regex and also deletes the `moreinfo` and `GoCats` rows from the df.

My expected Results:

```
     value
0   A067-M4FL-CAA-020
1   MRF2-050A-TFC
2   MZF8-050Z-AAB
3   MZA2-0580-TFD
```

I first removed the strings

```
del = ['hello', 'moreinfo']
for i in del:
   df = df[value!= i]
```

Can somebody suggest a way to use regex to match and delete all case that do match `A067-M4FL-CAA-020` or `MZF8-050Z-AAB` pattern so i don't have to create a list for all possible cases?

I was able to strip a single line like this but i want to be able to strip all matching cases in the dataframe

```
pattern = r',\w+ \,\w+-\w+\,\w+ *'
line = 'MRF2-050A-TFC,60 ,R-12,HT'
for i in re.findall(pattern, line):
   line = line.replace(i,'')

>>> MRF2-050A-TFC
```

I tried adjusting my code but it prints out the same output for each row

```
pattern = r',\w+ \,\w+-\w+\,\w+ *'
for d in df:
   for i in re.findall(pattern, d):
     d = d.replace(i,'')
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `df['value']=df['value'].str.replace(r"^([A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+){2,}).*|^(?:moreinfo|GoCats)$", r"\1")`, and then `df[df['value']!= '']`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
(?:\w+-){2,}[^,\n]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/18/)

Python scripts may be as follows

```
ss="""0   A067-M4FL-CAA-020
1   MRF2-050A-TFC,60 ,R-12,HT
2   moreinfo
3   MZF8-050Z-AAB
4   GoCats
5   MZA2-0580-TFD,60 ,R-669,LT"""

import re
regx=re.compile(r'(?:\w+-){2,}[^,\n]*')
m= regx.findall(ss)

for i in range(len(m)):
    print("%d   %s" %(i, m[i]))
```

and the output is

```
0   A067-M4FL-CAA-020
1   MRF2-050A-TFC
2   MZF8-050Z-AAB
3   MZA2-0580-TFD
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler approach you can try without using regex. pandas has many in-built functions to deal with text data.

```
# remove unwanted values
df['value'] = df.value.str.replace(r'moreinfo|60|R-.*|HT|GoCats|\,', '')

# drop na
df = df[(df != '')].dropna()

# print
print(df)

    value
0   A067-M4FL-CAA-020
1   MRF2-050A-TFC
3   MZF8-050Z-AAB
5   MZA2-0580-TFD

-----------
# data used
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u'''
    value
0   A067-M4FL-CAA-020
1   MRF2-050A-TFC,60 ,R-12,HT
2   moreinfo
3   MZF8-050Z-AAB
4   GoCats
5   MZA2-0580-TFD,60 ,R-669,LT'''),header=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest capturing the data you DO want, since it's pretty particular, and the data you do NOT want could be anything.

Your pattern should look something like this:

```
^\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{3}(?:-\d{3})?
```

https://regex101.com/r/NtH2Ut/2

I'd recommend being more specific than `\w` where possible.  (Like `^[A-Z]\w{3}`) if you know the beginning four character chunk should start with a letter.

**edit**
Sorry, I may not have read your input and output literally enough:

https://regex101.com/r/NtH2Ut/3

```
^(?:\d+\s+\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{3}(?:-\d{3})?)|^\s+.*
```